# bluetooth installed but cant detect other bluetooth devices

Tags: linux, bluetooth, ubuntu-12.04, bluez

I have installed bluetooth driver but it is not able to pair with other devices. It cant search for other devices.

OUTPUT of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0de9 (rev ff)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

output of dmesg | grep Bluetooth

```
[   15.744190] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   15.744212] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.744218] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.744220] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.744225] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.744503] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[   16.050311] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.050314] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.054600] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.054605] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.054607] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.750642] Bluetooth: hci0 command tx timeout
[   17.156673] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
```

i installed linux-firmware-nonfree but that doesnt help...I think the problem lies in the last two lines of the output of dmesg...Please help

Comment: I have few questions:
a. Do you see hciX device up?
    If not, as super user issue command: `hciconfig hci0 up`  
    On standard Linux like without hci0 device Bluetooth does not work.
b. Is bluetoothd up and running?
    If not, as super user issue command: `service bluetooth start`